# Necessary and sufficient condition to write a quadratic form on a finite-dimensional real vector space as a product of two linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms, dual-spaces

I have come across a tricky linear algebra problem. We want to prove that a quadratic form $q$ on a finite dimensional real vector space $V$ can be expressed as $q(v) = f_1(v)f_2(v) \iff r + |\sigma| \leq 2$, $\forall$ vectors $v \in V$, where $f_1, f_2 \in V^*$ are linear functionals in the dual space, $r$ is the rank of $q$, and $\sigma$ is the signature of $q$.

I have been thinking about this one for a while and simply have no idea how to approach it. A useful starting point is Sylvester's law, which states that the dimension of the maximal positive definite and negative definite subspaces is independent of choice of basis. For the $\Rightarrow$ direction I've tried considering the dimension of the subspace on which $q(v)$ is zero. This subspace is $\ker{f_1} + \ker{f_2}$, since if either $f_1(v), f_2(v) = 0$, we'll have $q(v) = 0$. The dimension of this is $\dim{\ker{f_1} + \ker{f_2}} = \dim{\ker{f_1}} + \dim{\ker{f_2}} - \dim{\ker{f_1} \cap \ker{f_2}} = n - r$. The subspace on which $q$ is positive definite is the subspace where $f_1, f_2$ have the same sign. The subspace on which $q$ is negative definite is where $f_1, f_2$ have different signs. But I didn't know where to take these ideas after this.

For $\Leftarrow$ I have no idea how to approach using the bound to pull out linear functionals.

I do not know how to think about this problem so I would appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: A bilinear form f on a finite dimensional Vector Space is a product of two linear functionals if and only if it is of rank one. Exercise problem from Hoffman (14.1, last problem, latest edition). The proof is not difficult if we proceed with ordered basis.

Answer (score 1):

$r + |\sigma| \leq 2$ covers four cases

- $r=2$ with signature $(+,-)$
- $r=1$ with signature $(+)$
- $r=1$ with signature $(-)$
- $r=0$

Equip $V$ with a positive-definite inner product $\langle,\rangle$.  Then $f_1, f_2$ can be written as
$$f_1(v) = \langle a,v\rangle, \quad f_2(v) = \langle b,v\rangle$$
for some $a, b\in V$.  If $W=\operatorname{span}\{a,b\}$ then $q(v)=0$ for $v\perp W$.  So $q$ is supported on $W$ and has rank $\le 2$.  If $v\in W$ then
$$q(v) = \|a\|\|b\|\|v\|^2\cos(\theta_{av})\cos(\theta_{bv})$$
where $\theta_{av}$ is the angle between $v$ and $a$
$$\cos(\theta_{av}) = \frac{\langle a,v\rangle}{\|a\|\|v\|}$$
and similarly $\theta_{bv}$ the angle between $v$ and $b$.

- Case 1: $a\ne 0$, $b\ne 0$, $a$ and $b$ are not collinear.  Let $\theta_{ab}\in (0,\pi)$ be the angle between $a$ and $b$.  Choosing a non-zero $v_1\in W$ that **bisects** the angle between $a$ and $b$, we have $\cos(\theta_{av_1}), \cos(\theta_{bv_1}) > 0$ so $q(v_1) > 0$.  OTOH, choosing a $v_2\in W$ at $90$ degrees to $v_1$, we get that $\cos(\theta_{av_2}), \cos(\theta_{bv_2})$ have opposing signs so $q(v_2) < 0$.  So in this case $r=2$ and signature $(+,-)$.
- Case 2: $a\ne 0, b\ne 0$ and $a, b$ collinear in the same direction.  In this case for non-zero $v\in W$ not perpendicular to $a$, $\cos(\theta_{av}), \cos(\theta_{bv})$ always have the same sign so it's the case $r = 1$ and signature $(+)$.
- Case 3: $a\ne 0, b\ne 0$ and $a, b$ collinear in opposite directions.  In this case for non-zero $v\in W$ not perpendicular to $a$, $\cos(\theta_{av}), \cos(\theta_{bv})$ always have opposite signs so it's the case $r = 1$ and signature $(-)$.
- Case 4: either $a=0$ or $b=0$.  Then $q=0$ so it's the case $r=0$.

This shows one direction that $q$ as a product of linear forms is one of the four cases.  For the other direction, If you have a symmetric bilinear form that's one of these cases, there's an orthonormal basis that diagonlizes it - and you can derive $a$, $b$ from the basis vectors.  The most complicated case $r=2$ for example in standard coordinates in a plane we have $q(x,y) = cx^2-dy^2$ with $c>0, d<0$ this factors as $q(x,y) = (\sqrt{c}x+\sqrt{d}y)(\sqrt{c}x-\sqrt{d}y)$.

Comment: Thank you for this, this works I think. I have since come up with a solution that does not require the additional structure of an inner product